# When dispatch_source_t is the timer, why does the thread keep changing when it's not the main thread?

Tags: objective-c

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0);
self.timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue);
dispatch_source_set_timer(self.timer, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_source_set_event_handler(self.timer, ^{
    NSLog(@"GCDTimer  %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
});
dispatch_resume(self.timer);
```

The print result is:

2020-08-04 15:01:43.185442+0800 MemoryMore1[7480:1418672] GCDTimer  <NSThread: 0x2806d5440>{number = 6, name = (null)}

2020-08-04 15:01:44.679590+0800 MemoryMore1[7480:1418673] GCDTimer  <NSThread: 0x2806b0dc0>{number = 5, name = (null)}

2020-08-04 15:01:45.679329+0800 MemoryMore1[7480:1418673] GCDTimer  <NSThread: 0x2806b0dc0>{number = 5, name = (null)}

2020-08-04 15:01:46.678351+0800 MemoryMore1[7480:1418673] GCDTimer  <NSThread: 0x2806b0dc0>{number = 5, name = (null)}

2020-08-04 15:01:47.679343+0800 MemoryMore1[7480:1418673] GCDTimer  <NSThread: 0x2806b0dc0>{number = 5, name = (null)}

2020-08-04 15:01:48.678826+0800 MemoryMore1[7480:1418674] GCDTimer  <NSThread: 0x28068f640>{number = 3, name = (null)}

When dispatch_source_t is the timer, why does the thread keep changing when it's not the main thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The queue has a couple of threads and will select one of these to use when the timer fires. If the queue is concurrent (as is the global queue) then it will select one even if another one is still running. If the queue is serial then it also will select from multiple threads, but only one will be running at a time.